# Magento2 refused to inject factory

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I have created a controller that uses the orderfactory because i need to load and modify a order.

The class looks like this:

```
class Accept extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_myFactory;
    protected $_orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Bla\Blabla\Model\myFactory $myFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_myFactory = $myFactory;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
       //some code
    }
}
```

Upon using this controller i get the following error:

> Argument 3 passed to Bla\Blabla\Controller\Callback\Accept::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory, none given

It worked at a start then it just refused to inject the factory. Can anyone see a problem with my code? I am going nuts over this.

Comment: Have you deleted var/di and var/generation ?

Comment: Solved it @MauroNigrele, one never tries the most simple thing until someone suggests it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool rm -rf seems to be the magento2 dev best friend :) I've created an answer for your question, could be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- remove [magento_root]/var/cache
- remove [magento_root]/var/di
- remove [magento_root]/var/generation

If you are working on PHP >= 5.5 check if op_cache is disabled if not restart PHP should clean the opcode cache.

Btw I'm assuming you have magento as developer mode